# Using UIAlertView delegate between two class

Tags: ios, uialertview

i have 2 classes, there is a UIAlertView in class B.I called alertView of class B in class A ,but B's alert view never enter its delegate method.

class A

```
B* b = [[b alloc]init];
[b check];
```

class B

```
-(void)check
{
       [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@“Tips” message:@“hello”  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@“Cancel” otherButtonTitles:@“Yes”, nil];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:    (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog();
    }
}
```

`
 i think it's the problem of delegate but i tried many method went in vain,how can i make it work.

Comment: can you provide code...?

Comment: What is location where you added delegate like alerview.delegate = self or anything else and post your code

Comment: You should use UIalertcontroller insted of alert view

Comment: First confirm that whether it is working in class b or not? If yes then assign parent class to class A with Class B and then you can call that method directly

Comment: Dh1_Bh1 i've already posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem is that you do NOT retain the object `b` after calling check. The UIAlertView delegate is a weak property - therefore if `b` gets released after you present the alert view calling `check` the delegate will be `nil` by the time the user interacts with the alert view. Keep a strong reference to `b` (e.g. use a strong property in class a) and try again.

I just want to add that UIAlertView is actually deprecated in iOS9 - if you don't need to support iOS7 you should use UIAlertController (with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert) instead of UIAlertView. UIAlertController is already available in iOS8 so you only really need to use UIAlertView if your app still supports iOS7.

Comment: wow...thanks..you solved my problem perfectly...and even a serial of these problem... :)

Comment: I just want to add that UIAlertView is actually deprecated in iOS9 - if you don't need to support iOS7 you should use UIAlertController (with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert) instead of UIAlertView. UIAlertController is already available in iOS8 so you only really need to use UIAlterView if your app still supports iOS7. All the best.

Answer (score -1):

Your class B should conform *UIAlertViewDelegate* protocol. And i agree with @tanzolone about retaining your object B.
Here is sample of code
Class A

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA()

@property (nonatomic) ClassB *classB;

@end

@implementation ClassA

- (void)yourMethodName {
    self.classB = [ClassB new];
    [self.classB check];
}

@end
```

ClassB

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassB()<UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ClassB

- (void)check {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tips" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"works");
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: @MiBrock i can't commenting now. Thank you for your notes about my answer